# Launch EMR and kill it after running one JOB (automatically)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, emr

I want to run a job each day automatically on Spark EMR, but i need to optimize my budget and use EMR only when I need it.

So, is there a way to run an EMR (AWS) just for one job, then kill all instances after the job is finished (each X day).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered the data pipeline service and I founded that this service allows to schedule and run spark jobs.
I think that this is the best solution for this use case.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-manage-recurring.html

Answer (score 2):

> You can run your cluster as a transient process: one that launches the
>   cluster, loads the input data, processes the data, stores the output
>   results, and then automatically shuts down. This is the standard model
>   for a cluster that performs a periodic processing task. Shutting down
>   the cluster automatically ensures that you are only billed for the
>   time required to process your data.

Under advanced options select ***Auto-terminate cluster after the last step is completed***.

[Configure a Cluster to be Transient or Long-Running](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-longrunning-transient.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, but is there a way to schedule the jobs ? for example, run it each day without creating an EC2 VM to control the scheduling

Comment: You could use datapipelines. You can configure a schedule within it to trigger the EMR at specified times. Further, you can configure notifications via SNS to notify you of success/failure scenarios. Minimizing the need to monitor the pipeline via logs etc.